# Outlook Add-in argument exception on body.getAsync() method

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, outlook-addin

According to https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Body.html:
The GetAsync() method takes in 3 parameters. The first one is the Coercion Type which [according to their documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.html#.CoercionType) is a string value. The other two parameters for GetAsync are options and callback which are optional.

My code: `var body = item.body.getAsync("html");`

which gives this exception:

`Exception details: outlook-web-16.00.js:formatted:5873 Uncaught Error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object cannot be converted to the required type.`

Am I not using the getAsync() method correctly? Most of the example code I've found online are using the callback parameter as well but if the options and callback parameters are optional and I only really need to get the contents of the email body as html, shouldn't this work?

P.S. This isn't an API versioning issue. I am definitely on 1.3 and body.getAsync does not return undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Am I not using the getAsync() method correctly? Most of the example code I've found online are using the callback parameter as well but if the options and callback parameters are optional and I only really need to get the contents of the email body as html, shouldn't this work?

Since this method is a asynchronous, to get the result we have to use the callback. This sample should work:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", processHtmlBody);
 function processHtmlBody(asyncResult) {
    console.log(asyncResult.value)
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) is a thread discussing getting the return value from asynchronous function using JavaScript.